# Solution of $p x (1 + x) r = y^p - 1$ in integers.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, congruences

The following equation does not seem to have any non-trivial integer solutions for prime $p\ge5$ and constant $r$:
$$p x (1 + x) r = y^p - 1$$

Could you please help with proving of assumption?

The solutions $x=0$,$r=0$ and $x=-1$ with $y=1$ are treated as trivial.

This is Thue equation so this means it has finite set of solutions.

What I have found so far which may help in proving:

1. (x,y)=1
2. (($y-1$),($1+...+y^{p-1}$))=$1$ or $p$

There are some other findings which I am not sure will help during the solving.

And also counterexamples are also something I was trying to find.

EDITED:

According to Michael Burr comment and taking into account the fact that the $x(x+1)$ is even:

$$y\equiv1\pmod{2p}$$

Comment: I am assuming that there is no non-trivial solutions. But frankly saying not sure about this.

Comment: Many thanks this is what I was trying to write there.

Comment: Looking at this $\!\!\mod p$ (and using Fermat's little theorem) it follows that $y\equiv1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: I think we can we say that $y\equiv1\pmod{2p}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any prime $p$, and any number $k\geq 1$. Define $y=2pk+1$.

Then by the binomial expansion one sees that $$r=\dfrac{y^p-1}{2p}\in \mathbb{N}$$
Then $x=1$ is a solution to your equation.

---

Instead of any $k$, pick $k=3$. Again $y=2pk+1=6p+1$. Then $$r=\dfrac{y^p-1}{6p}\in \mathbb{N}$$

This time $x=2$ is a solution.

---

It seems that you can build solutions by finding a suitable $k$ and $ r $ such that $$1+4\dfrac{(2pk+1)^p-1}{pr}$$
is a perfect square.

My method is first find a perfect square congruent to $1$ mod $4$, then adjust $k$ and $r$.

Comment: Actually the solution is correct in context of question. But can we improve this method to find some other solution with $x>1$.

Comment: Yes, see above :)